# IndexError: list index out of range (flask)

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app= Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")

url=[]

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def hello(): 
    websites= request.form.get("website")
    url.append(websites)
        
    filtered_url = []
    for items in url:
        if items != None:
            filtered_url.append(items)
    print(filtered_url)

    filtered_url1 = filtered_url[0].split(',')
    print(filtered_url1)

    return render_template("login.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am making python app and I want to just rearrange the list url so I can use it. I want to split one string separated by commas but when I try to run the code I get

> IndexError: list index out of range

Anyone have any idea why this is happening because this should work in theory

```
IndexError
IndexError: list index out of range

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/derek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/derek/Desktop/MasterSortNow/main.py", line 26, in hello
filtered_url1 = filtered_url[0].split(',')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That means `filtered_url` is empty. Check for that before trying to use the first element.

Comment: the list is not empty. when i run it without filtered_url1, i get an item in the list. could you please elobrate.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: The only place where you're using a list index is `filtered_url[0]`. The only reason that would ever cause this error is if the list is empty.

Comment: Why can't we see the output from *print(filtered_url)* in that output?

Comment: i have no idea.

Comment: @max OK - So how do you know that *filtered_url* is not an empty list?

Comment: because when i comment out (filtered_url1 = filtered_url[0].split(',')
    print(filtered_url1), i get ['https://www.wikipedia.org/, https://www.apple.com/, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4400812/marco-dufal']

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `“IndexError: list index out of range”`, avoid do not access a non-existing list index. For example, `my_list[5]` causes an error for a list with three elements.
If you access list elements in a loop, keep in mind that Python uses zero-based indexing: For a list with `n` elements, the first element has index 0 and the last index `n-1`.
A common cause of the error is trying to access indices `1, 2, ..., n` instead of using the correct indices `0,1, ..., (n-1)`.

Comment: thanks for your contribution. there is just one item in the list hence filtered_url[0].split(','). ideally this should work but it doesnt